Ubuntu 24.04 - how to record audio output from other apps?
I tried Audacity as there are instructions and it worked in the past.
But ALSA is no longer an option. (that was requires by the instructions)
I see "pulseaudio, pipewire and default" as recording devices, but nothing that seems to output audio.

Audio Recorder Turn on a favourite track in some Internet service (like YT for example) and run this program. The program also provides the ability to listen to recordings.

It is a Flatpak package so you will need to install Flatpak on your system to use it.
It's FOSS reference

is this some AI comment?  "Sound Recorder" does not even let me choose which input to record (just default input device)

Apologies, I selected the wrong app ... Answer updated accordingly and no, it wasn't AI generated - just my haste in trying to be helpful as ever.... I hope this one addresses your question.
